# List operation in Racket

Tags: racket

Is there list operation such like

'(x y)
'(1 2)

(substitution '(x y) '(1 2) (+ 'x 'y))

-> (each symbol relatively matched by number list, and substituted)

-> (x = 1, y = 2)

-> (+ 1 2)

-> 3

I cannot find any idea from reference.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `let`:

```
(let ((x 1)
      (y 2))
  (+ x y))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to represent a mapping between names and values (a "dictionary"), there are several ways to do it.  Racket provides a *hash* type that can associate names to values.  You can read about them in the [Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-tables.html).  There is a more generic approach to use dictionary-like values in Racket (described in the [racket/dict](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/dicts.html) library) that works across different data types, and not just hashes alone.